# why does my pc shut down when i am rendering my videos ?

Tags: cpu, shutdown, video-editing

I am attaching my system info details below please check it out if you need so.
I use premiere pro for light video editing and After effects too. Generally i don't use so much effect and other heavy stuff in my video just some typography and background music.

but when i hit render my pc shut down after a minute or two. 
I have tryied different editing software like premiere pro, vegas pro, etc 
also reducing resoulation like 1080p to 720p. but nothing works here

But many people suggest that i need more cooling on my pc since i am using AMD Processor , then i did it. Currently i have 2 extra cooling fan except cpu, gpu, psu fans... so tatal i have 5 cooling fan :D

After  all, its winter season here and the weather is very cold so, whats wrong now ? :P i have no idea..

**I have seen people using just dual core intel processor and rendering stuffs without any problem. I think my processor is better than dual core or core i3.

Some people says AMD processors are not for rendering stuffs but , all i need just 5-10 minutes video rendering.

i don't have any idea, can u help me giving any possible solution ?

Thank you

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393

Other OS Description    Not Available

OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation

System Name DESKTOP-BJH6T3U

System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

System Model    GA-970A-D3

System Type x64-based PC

System SKU
Processor   AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor, 3100 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Award Software International, Inc. F10, 5/30/2012
SMBIOS Version  2.4

Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Desktop
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States

Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.14393.206"
User Name   DESKTOP-BJH6T3U\Samir
Time Zone   Bangladesh Standard Time

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB

Total Physical Memory   7.98 GB

Available Physical Memory   4.93 GB

Total Virtual Memory    12.2 GB

Available Virtual Memory    8.93 GB

Page File Space 4.25 GB

Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes

Comment: Have you measured the temperatures of the different sensors while rendering?

Comment: Maybe check the windows logs (application or system) to see a more specific error message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a power delivery issue. It could be that your PSU can't handle the power draw of your components.